# Automatically updating a record using count() of another collection

Tags: mongodb, count

I have been looking at the docs and searching for videos on my problem, but I find nothing. I have a db called `HPDASH` where I have 2 collections, `scripts` and `serverList`. My problem is that I want to create a field for `serverList` that has the `count()` of the collection `scripts`.

I have tried this: 
`db.scripts.insert([{name: 'local_script'}, {name: 'qidsloader'}])` 
`db.serverList.insert({script_count: db.scripts.count() })`

The problem is that when I insert another record to scripts, the data on `scripts_count` stays as 2.

Is it possible to achieve this on MongoDB?

Comment: The short answer is no. Find the count whenever you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, MongoDB doesn't support naturally triggers. So, you need "programming skills" to do that functionality. You can use [mongoTriggers](https://github.com/iddogino/mongoTriggers), what can installed with [mongo-triggers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-triggers) npm package.

Answer (score 0):

A far more optimal solution exactly for this usecase would be use Redis to store the counts for the collection under a hashset while mongodb has the collection itself, this ensures your collection wont be locked for upserts, you can read more about this strategy [HERE](https://www.compose.com/articles/why-and-how-to-redis-with-your-mongodb/) (Disclaimer: not my website)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) which can track real-time changes in a database or collection and perform some task, like updating a document in another collection. Analogically, the functionality is similar to triggers in SQL databases.

Note that change streams can be used with replica-set and sharded clusters only. This feature is available since MongoDB <s>v4.2</s> v3.6.

In the question scenario, the `serverList` collection document can be updated with the current count of `scripts` collection after an insert or delete operation.

Also, see [Change Events](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/).